# Generate XSD from class in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, add-in, xsd.exe

It would be nice if, in Visual Studio 2010, I could right click a .cs class file and see a menu option to "Generate XSD", which would just be a shortcut to call through to xsd.exe. The generated XSD would then be automatically added to my project. Does anyone know of such a tool?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look here at this [site](http://wiki.evident.nl/%28S%28f0du2ky1azk12x3njviwetfi%29%29/Generating%20XSD%20from%20class%20file.ashx) explaining how to add to the external tools a way to call it directly from vss.

Just remember to use the right xsd.exe that target your project .net framework version.

For .net framework 4 use the one located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools

I hope this helps you.